# what the equivalent to OnResume on Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Right now, I am using **Xamarin.Forms** PLC project.

I have a label[x] on Page[x], then I will press button and go to Page[xx] ,then I will go back to Page[x] but I need to update Label[x] Text upon some Choices selected  on Page[xx]. 
Which Event should i use to update `Label.Text`? 
I was overriding `OnResuem()`Function on **Xamarin.android**, but it is not working on **Xamarin.forms**, I have no idea which is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick solution for this is:

-overriding the `OnAppearing()` method of the page and change the `label.Text` property once you change it on the other page

-Change the property to be public and change it on the other page

-Send the property to the next page as a parameter

but what you should do! is bind your property to a ViewModel and use OnPropertyChange() (Xamarin.Forms way and MVVM architecture) Events: a couple of tutorials how to understand this better:

https://blog.xamarin.com/advanced-data-binding-for-ios-android-and-windows/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how youre code works because you havent said. So I'm not sure how `Page[x]` knows about `Page[xx]` but it sounds to me like you want to use the `OnAppearing()` override.

Which from the [Xamarin.Forms Page API documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) states:

> When overridden, allows application developers to
>   customize behavior immediately prior to the Page becoming visible.

You could do this by adding the following to your *Page[x].xaml.cs* file

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   //Your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks user1 :) i accept another question because have more details